# Function call in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and I want to achieve this:

```
Foo.runtask param1: :asd, param2: :qwerty
```

I know how to create a function taking two parameters, but I want to know how to call it like I mentioned specifically "param1:" and "param2:"

Comment: `param1: :asd, param2: :qwerty` this is one argument. But you method accepts 2 parameters.

Comment: Can u please tell me how is it one argument? ',' does it count?

Comment: and if it's one argument would u tell me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`param1: :asd, param2: :qwerty` It is a shorthand for `{ param1: :asd, param2: :qwerty }`, which is a Hash (In some cases, you can omit the curlies of a Hash).

If you want to pass arguments like that, you method should accept a Hash as the parameter

eg

```
def my_method(options)
  puts options[:param1]
  puts options[:param2]
end
```

Then you can call `my_method param1: :asd, param2: :qwerty`

Comment: that's perfect. i tho have a question can i have paremeters for param1: and param2: predefined to compare what's been passed to the function with?

Comment: @FrederickCheung i am sorry i dont understand you

Answer (score 2):

From ruby 2.0 onwards ruby supports named arguments, so while you can still declare your method as just taking a single options argument you can also do

```
def foo(param1: 1, param2: :bar)
  ...
end
```

Deep down in the inside there is still a hash of arguments being passed around, but this allows you to specify default values easily (like normal default values these can be any ruby expression) and will raise an exception if you pass a names parameter other than a listed one.

In ruby 2.1 you can also have mandatory named arguments

```
def foo(param1: 1, param2:)
  ...
end
```

`param2` is now mandatory.

In both cases you invoke the method like before:

```
foo(param1: :asd, param2: :qwerty)
```

In fact just by looking at this invocation you can't tell whether these will be consumed as named arguments or as a hash

You can of course emulate this with hashes but you end up having to write a bunch of boilerplate argument validation code repeatedly.

To tell whether a parameter is taking its default value was passed explicitly you can use this well known trick

```
def foo(param1: (param_1_missing=true; "foo")
  ...
end
```

Here `param1` will be set to "foo" by default and `param_1_missing` will be true or nil